# Display dynamic title while page loading

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, title, angular-routing

I'm a newbie in the Angular. I have a problem with the set dynamic  while page loading. I want the page title will show title I defined in the router when the first time load page instead of loaded default title and set the  again.

Please take a look the image:
[image]

In the image: I want to show "My products" instead of "AngularDynamicPageTitles" after clicked refresh page. Can we do it? Or this is the behavior of Angular? If we can do it, please send me the example code.

This is my repository example code on GitHub:
[Repository example code](https://github.com/ducvuong-sutrix/dynamic-title-angular)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Until you manually set  the title after navigating to one of your routes, default title will be the one included in `index.html`'s title tags.

Comment: hi @David So we can't be set the title in router when loading page time?

Comment: I posted an answer exaplaining how you could do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the title text from your index.html file
But leave the tags there

```
<title>AngularDynamicPageTitles</title>
```

Comment: hi @Mathias, if remove the default title. The first time load page, the title will be blank. So have another solution for this case?

Comment: How about "Loading..."

Comment: This is probably more a browser issue and not Angular. And probably nobody but the developer would notice it is blank for a second.

Comment: You can see the image above. When I clicked refresh, it's loading page. And in this time, the default title will be display. If we remove it, the title in the tab of browser will be blank. I just want to display my title defined in router will display at this time instead of the default title or blank.

Comment: Yes, I will try your idea. Thanks a lot Mathias

Comment: Since angular is a single page application (SPA), the browser will just load the title that is present for that one page until you change it. Perhaps just place the real tiltle of your application in there until the real one can be loaded.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. Because the Angular is SPA and it just load the <head> once  so if we set or not set default <title>, it still the same until we change it by code js.
Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

By default, when loading an angular app, the title is the one specified in the `<title>` tag in `index.html` page; this until the angular app is initialised, routing done and title set in component or service.

If you want your title to appear faster, then you can use [angular universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to do server side rendering. The idea is that you angular code is executed server side, so when the page is initially rendered, the title is already set correctly.

This will also be useful for SEO, and other crawlers if you want them to see your page's metadata (title, description,....) and content